# Adding a new navigation node to sharepoint 2010 Top Navigation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to add a new navigation node to Top Navigation bar in my sharepoint website and I am using the following code:

```
public void AddNavigation(SPWeb web, String url, string module, string key)
{
    var resourceFile = "$Resources:" + module + "," + key;
    UnregisterGlobalNavigationLink(web, url);
    SPNavigationNode node = web.Navigation.GetNodeByUrl(url);
    if (node != null && overrideGlobalNavigationSetting) return node;
    node = new SPNavigationNode(resourceFile, url);
    node = web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar.AddAsLast(node);**//Exception here**
}
```

But I am getting an exception that I don't know how to resolve:

```
An unexpected error occured while manipulating the navigational structure of this Web.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an external node you want to add a another parameter `isExternal = true` to the node constructor, so it looks like this:

```
node = new SPNavigationNode(resourceFile, url, true);
```

EDIT: And by external I mean it points outside the site collection

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I applied this solution and the exception still happens.