# Sharepoint 2010 Global Navigation Data location in database

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am looking for a way to add or remove Global Navigation items from my sql server database.

I want to know where the data for global navigation is stored in sharepoint 2010 database schema.

I have seen some people (http://sharepointbabe.com/tag/navigation/) used NavNodes table but I can't find this table in my database.

Comment: Why do you want to make changes directly to the database?

Comment: Yes, I want to know where the related data are stored.

Comment: Notice that in the link provided in your question, the author did not modify the database through SQL Server (although she did query it to look at its contents). She ultimately resolved her problem using Powershell and the server-side SharePoint object model to make her changes.

Comment: Yes, this is the example which showed me that NavNodes should exist in my database, but it doesn't. And I am curious to find out where are the navigation data stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was looking at a wrong database. That table NavNodes must always exist in Sharepoint website content database. So the database I was looking at was another one which was made to hold membership information and other related information of the website.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the database directly is really a no-go. Use the API's to manage your environment:

Check this: https://discoveringsharepoint.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/programmatically-set-navigation-settings-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: I have tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049772/adding-a-new-navigation-node-to-sharepoint-2010-top-navigation

But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have you omitted the part where resources are used?

Comment: It seems that I was looking at a wrong database. That table NavNodes must always exist in sharepoint website content database.